# calculating values in python using formula for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have an excel sheet with the data below, here we need to calculate 2 columns based on other column values but I am getting NaN values

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the initial data
data = {'statMonthName': ['Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr'],
        'statWeek': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        'p_organic': [3646049.56, 3867696.284, 4051128.056, 4095508.5, 2778538.164, 2789640.51, 2736064.373, 3105200.772, 3112694.166],
        'f_organic': [2289567, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        'pct_diff': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]}

# Create a Pandas dataframe to store the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

in excel I am using the formula

```
f_organic = D2 =C2*(1+E1)
which means f_organic of x week  = p_organic of x week * (1+ pct_diff of (x-1) week)
```

and pct_diff is given as

```
pct_diff = =D2/C2-1
pct_diff = f_organic row2/ p_organic row 2 - 1
```

when I am trying to achieve this via python, I am failing and getting only null values

my code is below

```
# fill null values in f_organic and pct_diff columns

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.at[i, 'pct_diff'] = df.at[i, 'f_organic'] / df.at[i, 'p_organic'] - 1
    df.at[i, 'f_organic'] = df.at[i, 'p_organic'] * (1 + df.at[i-1, 'pct_diff'])
    

# print final dataframe
df
```

any help or suggestion is appreciated :)

Comment: Notice that the formula `pct_diff[i] = f_organic[i+1] / p_organic[i + 1] - 1` implies that the first value of `pct_diff` relies on the second value of`f_organic` (`NaN`), when you probably intended it to be the first (`2289567.0`).
This is why only `NaN` values will ever be produced.

Comment: Thank you, yes I want to use the first values of f_organic/p organic +1 as the formula for pct_diff. I tried to do the same. Can you please tell me what should I change in the formula? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I see that your code tries to do this. I found that the problem comes from the for loop itself, which misses the first value of `pct_diff` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame:

```
  statMonthName  statWeek    p_organic  f_organic pct_diff
0           Mar         1  3646049.560  2289567.0     None
1           Mar         2  3867696.284        NaN     None
2           Mar         3  4051128.056        NaN     None
3           Mar         4  4095508.500        NaN     None
4           Apr         5  2778538.164        NaN     None
5           Apr         6  2789640.510        NaN     None
6           Apr         7  2736064.373        NaN     None
7           Apr         8  3105200.772        NaN     None
8           Apr         9  3112694.166        NaN     None
```

Your formula (in array notation):

```
f_organic[i] = p_organic[i] * (1 + pct_diff[i-1])

pct_diff[i]  = (f_organic[i] / p_organic[i]) - 1
```

---

#### Correctly filling in the missing values

From your code that tries to fill in the missing values, the problem lies not in the formula, but in the way the `for` loop was constructed.

Since it starts with index `i=1` (the second row), it misses the value of `pct_diff[0]` (the first row). So all the calculations will involve null values, resulting only in `NaN`s.

A solution would be to first add a line outside the loop that fills in `pct_diff[0]`, and then reorder the code in the loop to reflect this:

```py
# Fill in the missing value of pct_diff on the first row.
df.at[0, 'pct_diff'] = df.at[0, 'f_organic'] / df.at[0, 'p_organic'] - 1

# Fill in the remaining values of f_organic and pct_diff.
for i in range(1, len(df)):

    # f_organic[i] = p_organic[i] * (1 + pct_diff[i-1])
    df.at[i, 'f_organic'] = df.at[i, 'p_organic'] * (1 + df.at[i-1, 'pct_diff'])
    
    # pct_diff[i] = (f_organic[i] / p_organic[i]) - 1
    df.at[i, 'pct_diff'] = df.at[i, 'f_organic'] / df.at[i, 'p_organic'] - 1


print(df)
```

Output:

```
  statMonthName  statWeek    p_organic     f_organic  pct_diff
0           Mar         1  3646049.560  2.289567e+06 -0.372042
1           Mar         2  3867696.284  2.428752e+06 -0.372042
2           Mar         3  4051128.056  2.543939e+06 -0.372042
3           Mar         4  4095508.500  2.571808e+06 -0.372042
4           Apr         5  2778538.164  1.744806e+06 -0.372042
5           Apr         6  2789640.510  1.751778e+06 -0.372042
6           Apr         7  2736064.373  1.718134e+06 -0.372042
7           Apr         8  3105200.772  1.949937e+06 -0.372042
8           Apr         9  3112694.166  1.954642e+06 -0.372042
```